# Call to a member function store() on null on Laravel with Nuxt

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am currently having issues saving in Laravel from my Nuxt Application. I tried to perform the creating data from my postman and it works. I don't know what I missing here.

> Controller

```
    $book = Book::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'about' => $request->about,
        // dd($request->file('image')),
        'image' => $request->file('image')->store('images'),
    ]);
```

> In my Nuxt template I have this

```
              <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" @submit.prevent="save">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name">Book Name</label>
                  <input
                    id="name"
                    v-model="editedItem.name"
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Book Name"
                  >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="image">Upload Book Cover</label>
                  <input
                    id="image"
                    name="image"
                    type="file"
                    accept="image/*"
                    class="form-control-file"
                    @change="onUpload"
                  >
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                  Create Book
                </button>
              </form>
```

> My nuxt methods

```
async save () {
  try {
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('name', this.editedItem.name)
    formData.append('image', this.editedItem.imageurl.name)

    await this.$axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/createbookapi',
      formData,
      {
        headers: {
          enctype: 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      }
    )
},
onUpload (e) {
  this.editedItem.imageurl = e.target.files[0]
},
data: () => ({
    editedItem: {
      name: '',
      imageurl: ''
  }),
```

When I tried to save using postman, it works.
I don't know what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

> Call to a member function store() on null

becouse your file is null to avoid this add validation or make it optional

example of optional image

#### make sure database field is nullable

```php
$book = Book::create([
    'name' => $request->name,
    'about' => $request->about,
    'image' => $request->hasFile('image')
        ? $request->file('image')->store('images')
        : null,
]);
```

---

for validation example

```php
'image' => 'required|file', // it should check for file because file have class have store method
```

Comment: I don't want it to be nullable. I must upload image alongside. I actually have this             'image' => 'required', in my validation. Don't want to post too much code.

Comment: @xtremeCODE i added validation code as well